# How would I produce a BodyGiro in Roblox to make sure the part is upright?

Tags: roblox

I don't know the numbers. I am bad with CFrames. What I need is to know how to make a BodyGiro that would make sure that the bottom face of a part is always facing down. I know the MaxTorque would be `Vector3.new(math.huge, 0, math.huge)`. But what would the CFrame be?

Comment: There's a very good write up on Understanding CFrames on the Roblox Developer Hub : https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Understanding-CFrame

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it ([from reading the reference](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/BodyGyro)), the CFrame property on BodyGyro is only used for its angular components. So basically it gives you the ability to set up a desired orientation of your part, by initializing it with x,y and z angles. Then you use MaxTorque to specify the amount of force you want to be allowed for each angle.

So for example:

```
-- create a part and float it in the air
local part = Instance.new("Part", game.Workspace)
local inTheAirHolder = Instance.new("BodyPosition", part)
inTheAirHolder.Position = Vector3.new(5,5,5) 

-- apply strong force on a desired x and z orientation
local gyro = Instance.new("BodyGyro", part)
gyro.MaxTorque = Vector3.new(math.huge, 0, math.huge)
```

Since the orientation by default is 0/0/0 it would float with the bottom facing down as you want.

Lets say you wanted it 10 degrees tilted, you would use the CFrame like that:

```
gyro.CFrame = CFrame.Angles(math.rad(10), 0, 0)
```